# Drawing convolutional diagrams like this

Tags: graphs, drawing, diagram, scientific-computing, neural-network

So I have been trying to draw one diagram similar to the image like this. So I was trying with draw.io and some success is there but how do we do insert image like below the RGBG in the reference image I posted. Which software/website is used here can anyone tell from this image?
Thanks for helping. [image]

Comment: You're probably looking for software that hasn't been updated since 2010, with that skeuomorphic look. It's been completely out of fashion for over a decade.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)